# Ionic: Routing gives a blank page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

im just starting to learn angular and ioninc to build an app.

I just started a new app with ionic included and made a list of items from a json file. This works perfect, but since im jump into routing i just see a blank page and i don't get my mistake.

this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Spätifinder</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionic.css">
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="spaetifinder">
        <ion-header-bar type="bar-positive" 
             animation="nav-title-slide-ios7" 
             back-button-type="button-icon" 
             back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back"></ion-header-bar>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized nav-title-slide-ios7">
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is ma app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('spaetifinder', ['ionic']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
        // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
        // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
        // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
        $stateProvider

            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home.html'
            });

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    });

app.controller('StoreController', [ '$http', function($http) {

        var store = this;

        store.storeList = [ ];

        $http.get('http://m.xn--sptifinder-r5a.de/apiv1/jsonp.php?action=list&lat=52.437595&long=12.987900&distance=100').success(function(data){
            store.storeList = data;
        });

        this.loadImage = function(hasImage){
            if(hasImage = 0) {
                return "http://www.spätifinder.de/images/fotos/no-foto.jpg";
            }
            else {
                return this.ID;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

and this should be my template for home (home.html)

```
<!-- our list and list items -->
        <ion-list>
          <a href="#" class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="spaeti in spaetis.storeList">
            <img ng-if="spaeti.has_image == 0" ng-src="http://www.spätifinder.de/images/fotos/no-foto.jpg">
            <img ng-if="spaeti.has_image == 1" ng-src="http://www.spätifinder.de/images/fotos/{{spaeti.ID}}_crop.jpg">
            <h2>{{spaeti.Name}}</h2>
            <p>{{spaeti.BusinessHours}}<br>{{spaeti.Street}}, {{spaeti.ZIP}} {{spaeti.City}}</p>
          </a>
        </ion-list>
```

Im just don't get it what is wrong with that, maybe you see an mistake there?

thanks in advance

luc

Comment: same problem what was the error?

Answer (score 3):

I think that your issue is in your routing configuration. You only define one state at the `/` URL. You then set your fallback to `/home` which doesn't exist. You probably want your home state to be located at `/home`.

Comment: Yes i think so too, but i don't see my mistake. I tried your fix but with the same result, but thanks a lot for this hint!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Scratch that i think i see your problem, you have a `;` at the end of your state block, i had to remove mine to get it to work it took me along time last night to figure that our, hope it helps you.

Old answer:

Im not sure maybe this will help but here is mine, the only thing i see wrong with yours is what @Jon7 already pointed out.

```
.state('main', {
        url: "/main",
        templateUrl: "templates/main.html",
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble understanding the routing too. I learned a lot from this Codepen example.

[Codepen example routing](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz)

Comment: This codepen doesn't works on my project. I get a blank page if I call index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add controller and perhaps a view as well...

**so from this**

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
});
```

to

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  views: {    //optional 
    'viewname':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        controller: 'StoreController' 
     }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the otherwise statement. It should be:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<p>Hello, world!</p>'
    })
})

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/